# Using excel to find missing daily logs for people

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comparison

I have an excel file with 2 worksheets.

One has a list of daily logs and looks like this:

```
Staff Person | Shift Date | Start Time | End Time
John | Oct 31 | 8:00 AM | 4:00 PM
John | Nov 3 | 2:00 PM | 10:00 PM
```

Another has the schedule list and looks like this:

```
Staff Person | Date | Start | End
John | Oct 31 | 8:00 AM | 4:00 PM
John | Nov 1 | 8:00 AM | 4:00 PM
John | Nov 2 | 8:00 AM | 12:00 PM
John | Nov 3 | 2:00 PM | 10:00 PM
```

I want to compare the two worksheets based on all the columns (since the sheets have multiple people in them) and highlight the schedule worksheet rows that don't have a daily log entered. I was thinking of using conditional formatting and entering a formula.

Does anybody out there know how I could do this? I do not have an SQL database and so I can't run an SQL query unfortunately.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Do the log and schedule values match exactly or does the log e.g. contain the actual clock in / clock out time?

Comment: @BradR I'm using Excel 2016

Comment: @ExcelEverything Yes, the log and schedule values match exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365:

```
=NOT(OR(BYROW(A2:D2=Daily!A2:D1000, LAMBDA(entry, AND(entry)))))
```

Explanation:

1. Do a row comparison with a whole table, which will return a boolean table with true values if a cell matched
2. Do a AND for each row in the boolean table using BYROW - this is to make sure that each cell in a row matched and not just say the name or the time. The result will be a boolean column vector with TRUE values if the schedule row matched the corresponding daily log row.
3. Since we don't care where the match occurred, or how many times, simply OR these all together into a single boolean value -TRUE is the schedule row occurred in at least one row of the daily log.

Note: If you don't have Office 365, you could create a single lookup value column and concatenate all the strings in a row together e.g.

```
=A2&B2&C2&D2
```

Do this in both sheets, say in column E. Now do a single column comparison:

```
=NOT(OR(E2=Daily!E2:E1000))
```

You might have to commit this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, to tell Excel it is an array formula (version of Excel depending). Also if OR doesn't work, use BITOR.

Comment: Thank you! This is super useful. Take care :)